# POST with curl according to a particular format

Tags: post, curl

I'm attempting to gather XML data automatically using curl, and my command so far is

```
curl -E keyStore.pem -d 'uid=myusername&password=mypassword&active=y&type=F' 'https://www.aidaptest.naimes.faa.gov/aidap/XmlNotamServlet HTTP/1.1/' -k
```

but it keeps on giving me a "Your browser sent a query this server could not understand." error.

I'm pretty sure that it's connecting since it's not rejecting me, but I don't know how to properly format the POST. Here's some documentation they gave me for the format of the POST request.

```
POST <URL>/aidap/XmlNotamServlet HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length:  <input_parameter’s length>
<a blank line>
<input_parameter>`
```

input_parameter is uid, password, and location_id bit and is correct

Am I doing this correctly from what you can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
curl -E keyStore.pem -v -X POST -i --header Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 -d 'uid=myusername&password=mypassword&active=y&type=F' 'https://www.aidaptest.naimes.faa.gov/aidap/XmlNotamServlet'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `HTTP/1.1` at the end of the URL in the command line. And even if you needed it, you certainly don't need the final `/` character before the closing single quote.